# Slice HTML according to headers

Tags: html, node.js, cheerio

I have a HTML document, which looks more or less like this:

```
<h1><a id="first-id"></a>First header</h1>
<h2>Foo</h2>
<p>Some text</p>
<h3>Bar 1</h3>
<p>Some text</p>
<h3>Bar 2</h3>
<p>Some text</p>
<h3>Bar 3</h3>
<p>Some text</p>
<h2>Baz</h2>
<p>Some text</p>
<h3>Bar 4</h3>
<p>Some text</p>
<h3>Bar 5</h3>
<p>Some text</p>
<h1>Second header</h1>
```

All headers can additionally have one or more anchor tags (like the first header) inside them.

My goals are:

- to split the document by `h1` tags
- to be able to process the content between the `Bar \d` separately

I.e. I want to get the following parts separately:

```
<h1><a id="first-id"></a>First header</h1>
<h2>Foo</h2>
<p>Some text</p>
```

```
<h3>Bar 1</h3>
<p>Some text</p>
```

```
<h3>Bar 2</h3>
<p>Some text</p>
```

```
<h3>Bar 3</h3>
<p>Some text</p>
```

```
<h2>Baz</h2>
<p>Some text</p>
```

```
<h3>Bar 4</h3>
<p>Some text</p>
```

```
<h3>Bar 5</h3>
<p>Some text</p>
```

```
<h1>Second header</h1>
```

Until now, I played around with `cheerio`, but I wasn't able to find a method to nicely slice the HTML into different parts.

How can I achieve my goals? Is there a library better suited for my needs? I want to avoid pure string manipulation, since it will most likely mess up all anchor tags...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to iterate with nextUntil:

```
$('h1').each((i, h1) => {
  console.log('-' + $.html($(h1)))
  let $2 = cheerio.load($.html($(h1).nextUntil('h1')))
  $2('h2,h3').each((i, h2) => {
    console.log('--' + $.html($(h2)))
    console.log('---' + $.html($(h2).nextUntil('h2,h3')))
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a good practice to put the html code of the segments in between div tags with a id and target the div's by id as so:

```html
<div id="firstHeader">
  <h1><a id="first-id"></a>First header</h1>
  <h2>Foo</h2>
  <p>Some text</p>
  <h3>Bar 1</h3>
  <p>Some text</p>
  <h3>Bar 2</h3>
  <p>Some text</p>
  <h3>Bar 3</h3>
  <p>Some text</p>
  <h2>Baz</h2>
  <p>Some text</p>
  <h3>Bar 4</h3>
  <p>Some text</p>
  <h3>Bar 5</h3>
  <p>Some text</p>
</div>

<div id="secondHeader">
  <h1>Second header</h1>
</div>
```

And then target by javascript using this:

```js
const firstHeader = document.getElementById('firstHeader')
const secondHeader = document.getElementById('secondHeader')
```

Not sure if this is what you meant.

Comment: Sadly not quite. I'm parsing a Word document to HTML, which puts out the structure I mentioned. Therefore there are no `div`s surrounding my headers. Plus, the `id`s are not fixed, as the document gets updated frequently.

Comment: Aw, sorry. Hope you'll get a good answer soon. Good luck with your endeavours as I cannot help you with your problem.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for not being too clear with my question...